# SearchView in android displaying query text at list view footer

Tags: android, android-listview, searchview, android-filterable

I have implemented the SearchView of android at actionbar for searching the listview, everything is working fine but the queried text in SearchView is getting displayed as shown below[image: Black color text at bottom is hiding my button]

this is the code i have written

```
searchView.setQueryHint("Query Hint");
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

Anyone please help me on how to remove that view

This is the code regarding the search view.

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
....
OnCreate(){
...
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
OnCreateOptionsMenu()
{...
setUpSearchView();
...}

    private void setupSearchView() {
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Product");
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    }

@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            listView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            listView.setFilterText(newText);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Adapter code is as below.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    private Activity activity;
    private List<Product> productItems;
    private List<Product> orig;


    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> productItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.productItems = productItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return productItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return productItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ProductHolder productHolder;

         ....

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                final List<Product> intermediateResults = new ArrayList<Product>();
                if(orig == null)
                    orig = productItems;
                if(constraint != null)
                {
                    if(orig!=null && orig.size() > 0){
                        for (final Product g : orig) {
                            if (g.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))
                                intermediateResults.add(g);
                        }
                    }
                    filterResults.values = intermediateResults;
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                productItems = (ArrayList<Product>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some more of your code ?

Comment: prolly because `lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true)` or something similar ... if you are using SearchView there is no need to setting this

Comment: @JonasCz  Code added.. Please help me to solve this

Comment: @Selvin without listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true); filter not working..

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278385/how-to-remove-android-searchview-popup-text-while-searching