# Weird gray popup with text when typing in SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I have a SearchView in my app and when I type in it, every character shows up in a weird popup as can be seen below.

[image: Example]

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="com.example.myapp">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:queryHint="@string/select_story_query_hint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@color/gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/create_new_story_button"
        android:id="@+id/createStoryButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/low_priority_button_background"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/done"
        android:id="@+id/select_story_done"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
mSearchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.query_hint));
```

Listener:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        mListView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        mListView.setFilterText(newText);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I can't seem to find anything about this issue when I search (guess I am not using the correct keywords). This is also happening on multiple devices running different versions of Android (N5 with 5.1, O+O with 4.4) and only this particular field has this issue, all other EditText fields have no issue.

Comment: Is this search widget placed in ToolBar or ActionBar? If so, it could show up the menu title OR it tries to show something like an autocomplete popup.

Comment: @Stan Its in a fragment layout. I have update the question with the full layout code.

Comment: Check this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278385/how-to-remove-android-searchview-popup-text-while-searching

Comment: It looks like a prompt of AutoCompleteEditText which, I guess, is included in SearchView itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with a built in functionality of `ListView`'s filter functionality. As JonasCz pointed out, how to solve this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278385/how-to-remove-android-searchview-popup-text-while-searching). My code changes to the `onQueryTextChange()` method to fix this (basically use the `Adapter`'s filter functionality):

```
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        Filter filter = adapter.getFilter();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            filter.filter("");
        } else {
            filter.filter(newText);
        }
        return true;
    }
```