# Text appear in grey popup instead of menu search

Tags: android, search, keyboard

I have a menu_search in actionbar like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/searchable"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"
    />
</menu>
```

and `onCreateOptionsMenu` in activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                listSongs.clearTextFilter();
            } else {
                Custom ca = (Custom) listSongs.getAdapter();
                ca.getFilter().filter(newText);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

I'm very interested why text doesn't appear in search menu in actionbar while typing? But it is shown in grey popup above the keyboard. What could be the reason of such behaviour? I read something about grey popup in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253882/weird-gray-popup-with-text-when-typing-in-searchview) post, but the difference is: it has text shown in searchview. I haven't found any official documentation that describe this grey popup. Appreciate any advice or link.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

And Below code to get search result

```
 SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener onQueryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            searchResult(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            searchResult(query);
            return false;
        }
    };

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(onQueryTextListener);
```

Comment: It is inside onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: Yes, inside the onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but problem still exist. I think it more complex, because I have Mediaplayer in activiry, maybe it play some role