# How to remove screen overlay from searchview in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, searchview

As the title states, I would like to know how to remove the screen overlay from the `SearchView`. It's a bit ugly and annoying. Plus it gets in the way. ***I'm using*** `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`.

**Here's what it looks like:**

[image: searchview overlay]

Comment: Can you test on another device or an emulator? I have never seen this while working with SaerchView.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I found a similar SO question with an answer but it doesn't work for me: [Link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278385/how-to-remove-android-searchview-popup-text-while-searching)

Comment: Please share some code for your searchView and Filter (if any)

Comment: @SteveC. - Can we see the codes? and you mean the test with that shadow overlay?

Comment: @SteveC. - I think the SearchView hasn't any problem, let's see the layout then i can fix that for ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done like below, and I get no any overlay.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_city);
searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
searchView.setQueryHint("Search View Hint");

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        //Log.e("onQueryTextChange", "called");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {


        // Do your task here

        return false;
    }

});

return true;
}
```

Comment: The OP said: `i'm using android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` and your codes doesn't have `MenuItemCompat` for V7 library.